# How to copy file path with ranger on SSH

Tags: ranger

I login into my machine via SSH, and use Ranger as a file manager.

When I use commands of copying file path like `yn`, the name is not copied to the clipboard.

How can I make it being copied to the Windows clipboard?

I can settle for the name being selectable with mouse, or any other way to get the name to other windows.

Answer (score 1):

Good Morning, I am using i3 (4.16.1-1) on manjaro linux (18.0.4), my terminal is URxvt (9.22-7) and ranger (1.9.2-1).
I used "yp" (yank path) in ranger and in terminal "SHIFT-INSERT" to paste in terminal. Hope this helps.

**(edit 20190516):** Thanks for your reply

To enable clipboard management (xsel and xclip) in ssh:
I found 2 methods:

**Method (1)**: Easier but have security problems with ssh:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12772/227220

in server:

- edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config with root privilege and set "X11Forwarding
  yes"
- install xauth

in local machine:

- start ssh with option -Y to enable trusted X11 forwarding.
- now use ranger's commands to copy paths to clipboard... (yn|yd|yp)

**Method (2):** 
use ssh without X11Forwarding (more secure).

in ranger:
":shell echo -n %d > ~/tmp.txt"
%d = current directory
or
%p = current path
or
%n = current filename

Back in your local machine:
copy saved text to clipboard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18893823
ssh [your server] -p 2222 "cat ~/tmp.txt" | xclip -selection p

Comment: The question mentions using SSH.

Comment: @RalfFriedl Thanks, please review my new edit.

Answer (score 0):

To enable clipboard management (xsel and xclip) in ssh: I found 2 methods:

Method (1): Easier but have security problems with ssh: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12772/227220

in server:

```
edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config with root privilege and set "X11Forwarding yes"
install xauth
```

in local machine:

```
start ssh with option -Y to enable trusted X11 forwarding.
now use ranger's commands to copy paths to clipboard... (yn|yd|yp)
```

Method (2): use ssh without X11Forwarding (more secure).

in ranger: ":shell echo -n %d > ~/tmp.txt" %d = current directory or %p = current path or %n = current filename

Back in your local machine: copy saved text to clipboard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18893823 ssh [your server] -p 2222 "cat ~/tmp.txt" | xclip -selection p